# Optoma E761 lamp projector showing horizotal black stripes

Tags: vga, projector

I have an Optoma E761 lamp projector which I've tried to connect to both a win7 desktop PC through VGA and Dell Inspiron I5000 win10 laptop. All what I'm getting is horizontal black stripes and clusters of black pixels. Also, the button on both the projector and remote control are simply unresponsive. The only button working is the power on/off button. I've tried:

1. cleaning the ports
2. replacing the USB and VGA cable
3. Pressing the enter button for 7-10 seconds to reset.

[image: I've provided an image for you guys to get a better look at the issue]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks borked. Also very old and low-spec by today’s standards. Time to get a new one. // This is a DLP projector. The DLP is chip is mechanical and could simply be damaged.

Comment: @DanielB Is there anyway to make sure of that?